# Class referenced in the layout file, androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout, was not found in the project or the libraries error messages

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, build.gradle, android-constraintlayout

I recently updated my android studio to  android studio arctic fox v2020.3.1. After adding **implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0")**, to my build.gradle file, my xml classes shows this error: **Class referenced in the layout file, androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout, was not found in the project or the libraries**, how do I add the android navigation library and the dagger-hilt library without having my constraint layout class go missing?

[build.gradle file(:app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N5Om.png)

[build.gradle file(:app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myvx1.png)

[build.gradle file(:app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgJtV.png)

[build.gradle file:(appname)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yznd.png)

[An image of the error in the xml files]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXbqe.png

Comment: File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart